# Use Mockito/Power Mockito to mock a private method

Tags: java, mockito, testng

I need to use Mockito/Power Mockito to mock a private method. I am using testng, and most of the examples I see online are for mocking private method using PowerMock+Junit - [Mocked private method with PowerMock, but underlying method still gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057607/mocked-private-method-with-powermock-but-underlying-method-still-gets-called)

Can anyone please point me to examples where I can use Power Mockito+testng. I have been looking for a while, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spy, refer below link
https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method

Also, using whitebox you can do this
[How to mock private methods using Whitebox(org.powermock.reflect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150117/how-to-mock-private-methods-using-whiteboxorg-powermock-reflect)

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples with PowerMock and PowerMockito , right off of SO:

- [How to mock private method for testing using PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock)
- [Mock private method using PowerMockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121177/mock-private-method-using-powermockito)

Answer (score 0):

i found the way . please try this

```
 @Test
        public  void  commandEndHandlerTest() throws  Exception
        {
            Method retryClientDetail_privateMethod =yourclass.class.getDeclaredMethod("Your_function_name",null);
            retryClientDetail_privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            retryClientDetail_privateMethod.invoke(yourclass.class, null);
        }
```