# How to mock a single method in java

Tags: java, mocking

Is it possible to Mock a single method of a Java class?

For example:

```
class A {
    long method1();
    String method2();
    int method3();
}


// in some other class
class B {
    void someMethod(A a) {
       // how would I mock A.method1(...) such that a.method1() returns a value of my
       // choosing;
       // whilst leaving a.method2() and a.method3() untouched.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `Mockito's` spy mechanism:

```
A a = new A();
A aSpy = Mockito.spy(a);
Mockito.when(aSpy.method1()).thenReturn(5l);
```

The use of a spy calls the default behavior of the wrapped object for any method that is not stubbed.

[Mockito.spy()](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T))/[@Spy](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Comment: Or, as documented, [in some cases](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn(java.lang.Object)) you'd need `Mockito.doReturn(51).when(aSpy).method1();`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot spy on an instance of a final class this way. :(

Comment: Generally, it's impossible to mock any final thing. Also methods in final class treats as final too.

Comment: @JohnB how can we use `Mokito spy` to mock private method?

Comment: Try PowerMockito: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock

Comment: @PhilipRego the question did not ask how to use mocking with methods that take arguments. There is already plenty of discussion about that as doing so for a spy is no different than for a mock. I think adding that would have complicated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with methods that return void either.

Comment: @tschumann Consider Mockito.doNothing().when(aSpy).method1();

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`spy()` method from Mockito](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy%28T%29), and mock your method like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

...

A a = spy(new A());
when(a.method1()).thenReturn(10L);
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on Mockito's documentation the accepted answer is not the correct way to Spy real objects.

The right way to do this is to use the following pattern: 
`doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);`

Below you can find the snippet from Mockito's about [Spying on real objects](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13).

> Important gotcha on spying real objects! 
> Sometimes it's impossible or
> impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore when
> using spies please consider doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods
> for stubbing. Example:
>
> ```
> List list = new LinkedList();    
> List spy = spy(list);
>
> //Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)   
> when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");
>
> //You have to use doReturn() for stubbing   
> doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
> ```
>
> Mockito *does not* delegate calls
> to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it.
> So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect
> the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real
> instance state. The corollary is that when an *unstubbed* method is
> called *on the spy* but *not on the real instance*, you won't see any
> effects on the real instance. Watch out for final methods. Mockito
> doesn't mock final methods so the bottom line is: when you spy on real
> objects + you try to stub a final method = trouble. Also you won't be
> able to verify those method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jmockit:

```
public void testCase(@Mocked("methodToBeMocked") final ClassBoBeMocked mockedInstance) {
           new Expectations() {{
                   mockedInstance.methodToBeMocked(someParameter); returns(whateverYouLikeItToReturn);
           }}

   mockedInstance.callSomemethod();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could simply create a subclass of `A` that overrides `method1()`.

Comment: This wouldn't work - since you'd have to pass in an existing instance of A into the subclass of A in order for subclass to return a.method2() and a.method3() for calls to method2() and method3() respectively. Which means the subclass would have override method2() and method3().

Comment: @user63904: ah, so you want to modify the behaviour of method1 INSIDE someMethod() while still working with the instance of A that has been passed as a parameter? Right, that wouldn't work then.