# Java Mock object, without dependency injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, mocking

I am interested in Mocking objects in a JUnit test-suite, however I have only come across mocking frameworks that use dependency injection to inject mock objects. However, I would like to be able to mock classes/functions without having to inject that mock object, along the lines of @patch() in python.

Trivial example:

```
//dependency injection
public String bar(Foo foo) {
    return foo.foo(); //just pass in mock Foo object
}
//.... onto test code
Foo mockedFoo = <Mocked Foo object>;
String response = bar(mockedFoo);
assertEqual(response, <mockedFoo return value>);


//case I am looking for
public String bar() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(); //how to create mock object here?
    return foo.foo(); //or simply how to mock a single function?
}
//... onto test code
<force the Foo class or foo method to be mocked from here without touching bar() source code>
String response = bar();
assertEqual(response, <mocked response>);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895605/how-to-mock-a-single-method-in-java

Comment: Use a library, e.g. Mockito. Or in simpler cases, extend `Foo` or even better, implement the same interface as `Foo` to get a simple mock.

Comment: Mike, from looking through Mockito, it still appears that dependencies have to be injected. Please see above for edit to increase clarity.

Comment: @Kamoor1982, the author of that post appears to be asking the opposite of what I am asking.

Comment: Anyone knows of a solution with c# instead of java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Powermock to instrument the class under test to return a mock when `new` is called.

[Powermock mock constructor tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

your code would look like this:

```
RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( Bar.class )
public class BarTest {


@Test
public void test(){
   Foo mockedFoo = createMock(Foo.class);
   //set up mockedFoo here
   ...

   //This will make a call  to new Foo() inside Bar.class
   //return your mock instead of a real new one
   expectNew(Foo.class).andReturn(mockedFoo);

   ...
   replay(mockedFoo, File.class);

   Bar bar = new Bar();
   String response = bar.bar();

   assertEqual(response, <mocked response>);

   verify(mockedFoo, File.class);


}

}
```

Comment: if I am not wrong, expectNew is only implemented for use with EasyMock, not with Mockito. For Mockito, use whenNew instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you could mock Foo like this

```
public String bar() {
    Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    return foo.foo();
}
```

The problem with this though is that `foo.foo()` will essentially do nothing as you haven't defined what `#foo()` should return when we call the mocked version. Using a more complete example you could do something like this:

```
class MyTest {

    Foo mockedFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(mockedFoo.foo()).thenReturn("This is mocked!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        String returnedFoo = mockedFoo.foo();
        Assert.assertEquals("This is mocked!", returnedFoo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, modified my post to aid in clarity. It appears that this response answers a question a tad different from what I was asking, sorry about.