# catching an exception after doThrow JUNIT

Tags: java, exception, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a JUnit test where I am testing a method with null arguments. If the argument /arguments are null, then I would throw a NullPointerException. The method by itself will just throw an IOException. I am using doThrow on mock object of the class  but it seems to me that I am losing the exception in the doThrow() construct and I am unable to catch it. Additionally, I strictly do not want to use a try catch in my unit tests. So I am using @Rules for the same. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class TableTest {

@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
private static Table spyTable;

@Test
public void testCreateTableWithNullTableName_throwsIOEXception() throws IOException {
    final String tableName = null;
    mockConfig = mock(Configuration.class);
    spyPersonTable = spy(new PersonTable());
    doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(spyPersonTable).createTable(tableName, mockConfig);
    // exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
}
```

Using the @rule's exception object, If I use the commented line to catch my exception, the exception created in the doThrow() construct will be lost and I cannot catch it. My unit test will fail and complain that:

```
Expected test to throw an instance of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The test works fine if I the line is commented as I have it. Here is how my method looks like that I am trying to test:

```
public void createTable(final String tableName, final Configuration config) throws IOException
```

The method needs to throw IOException since the specific exception thrown during table creation is a subclass of IOException.

Is my catching of exception in the JUnit test wrong for this type of checking exception.

Comment: " I strictly do not want to use a try catch in my unit tests" <-- why, if it can cure the problem?

Comment: Just a requirement that is given to me.

Comment: And is there an exception which is actually thrown?

Comment: Well, the method "createTable" just does not throw the IllegalArgumentException specifically. At the beginning of the method body, I have Preconditions that check for null and so on

Comment: And the precondition is what? If `.checkNotNull()` it will throw an NPE on failure, not an `IllegalArgumentException`. You shouldn't have to `.doThrow()` if this is the case, not even `spy()` is since this is the only thing you want to test

Comment: This is how I am doing it:  Preconditions.checkArgument(!(tableName.isEmpty()) || (!(tableName.equals(null))), "tableName cannot be null or empty");

Comment: OK, why don't you just create a normal `PersonTable` and call `table.createTable(null, null);`? If your construct above can actually capture the IllegalArgumentException then it should work.

Comment: Also, your test name seems to imply that you expect this operation to throw an IOException. Uh. So, what is what?

Comment: doThrow needs a mock object. It will not allow me to call the method createTable with a real object

Comment: Yes, and that is a mistake imho. You want to create the behaviour of `createTable` so why mock its behaviour??

Comment: so what do you suggest doing ? I am kinda confused here

Comment: See my answer; I have always done this way and it has always worked for me... I don't know how to use your `@Rule`, so you'll have to adapt that code.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to test whether that method throws an exception; but by using `doThrow().when(sut).createTable(...)` you *prevent* the SUT from having its normal behaviour.

Just do:

```
final PersonTable table = new PersonTable();
table.createTable(null, null); // theoretically throws IllegalArgumentException
```

And just check that there is a thrown exception. No idea how you do that with your `@Rule` but I don't use that and here how I'd do that:

```
final PersonTable table = new PersonTable();
try {
    table.createTable(null, null);
    fail("No exception thrown!");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "the expected message");
}
```

Comment: This test still fails but I get the idea behind it and can take it from here. I still dont understand that when I say something like : public void someTestName() throws IOException{

} but I also throw an IllegalArgumentException if I pass null arguments. Should I also throw this exception too in the testName declaration ?

Comment: You needn't do that, since `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception

Comment: the reason for throwing IOException is that, my createTable method throws an IOException and any test method that makes calls to this method need to throw an IOException

Comment: Then don't use `Preconditions` ;)

Comment: damn....dont want to have so many design changes when i have stuff to be reviewed..!!!

Comment: OK, what if you posted another question with your code, what you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: nope. Will not do that. I don't doubt your answers bro. I just wanted to check if I am wrong here as I am new to the mocking framework.

Comment: Well, using `Preconditions` will throw an IllegalArgumentException; you should not use it if you want `IOException` to be thrown in all cases...

Comment: You may want to have a look to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426313/how-to-verify-that-an-exception-was-not-thrown/17428439#17428439

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your test doesn't actually call `createTable`, and therefore there's nothing to throw the exception.  You *could* write this.

```
@Test
public void testCreateTableWithNullTableName_throwsIOEXception() throws IOException {
    final String tableName = null;
    mockConfig = mock(Configuration.class);
    spyPersonTable = spy(new PersonTable());
    doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(spyPersonTable).createTable(tableName, mockConfig);
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    spyPersonTable.createTable(tableName, mockConfig);
}
```

But I don't really see the point of doing that, because you'd really just be testing Mockito.  You're stubbing the method so that it does nothing other than throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, then checking that your stubbing worked OK - which seems pointless to me.