# Junit Mocking Private Method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I need to mock private method and should return true. In ServiceImpl-execute() my request will go to else { } and it will call "eventRequest()".
Its a private boolean eventRequest(), So whenever evenRequest() will call i should return true. Can anybody help me out

**ServiceImplTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceImpl.class})
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    public void testExecute() {
        Response response = serviceImpl.execute(request);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pushResponse);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, pushResponse.isIsSuccess());
    }
}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
public class ServiceImpl {
    public Response execute(Request request) {
        Response response = null;
                boolean isSuccess;
                if (returnMockResponse(request, notifyRqst)) {
                    isSuccess = true;
                } else {
                    isSuccess = eventRequest(notifyXmlRqst);
                }
        response = ResponseBuilder.createResponse(isSuccess);
        return response;
    }

    // Need to mock below private method and should return true.
    private boolean eventRequest(String request) throws Exception {
        return eventNotifyResponse.isIsSuccess();
    }
}
```

**ResponseBuilder.java**

```
public class ResponseBuilder {
    public Response createResponse(boolean result) {
            Response response = new Response();
            response.setIsSuccess(result);
            return response;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Don't mock a private method. Just mock the eventNotifyResponse to return true when calling isIsSuccess(). Also, why are you passing an unused String to the method?

Comment: Have some condition check with that string so i'm passing string.

Comment: @Manu , We can't do that because before calling eventNotifyResponse.IsSuccess(); we have some more codes to verify some other logic but i want to skip that and return true, when we call eventRequest(notifyXmlRqst)

Comment: Have a look to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock). Posible duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mock of eventNotifyResponse normally, then use Whitebox to set the private (internal) field.

Assuming your field eventNotifyResponse was of a type named EventNotifyResponse, the test class it would be something like:

```
    EventNotifyResponse evtNotifyResponseMock = mock(EventNotifyResponse.class);
    when(evtNotifyResponseMock.isIsSuccess()).thenReturn(true);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(serviceImpl, "eventNotifyResponse", evtNotifyResponseMock);
```

Whitebox is a class of Powermock (org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox).
setInternalState is overloaded. In the example, the parameters used are:

1. the target object to inject into (your object being tested)
2. the name of the internal field to be setted (String)
3. the value itself, in this case a mock

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in jUnit or jMock by default, you can either change the private to public or you can invoke the public method which internally invokes the private method, and make sure that input causes the private method to get called and covered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with `PowerMock.createPartialMock(ClassWithPrivateMethod.class, "nameOfTheMethodToMock")` and `PowerMock.expectPrivate(mockObject, "nameOfTheMethodToMock", argument1, argument2)` as describe in the wiki off powermock ?

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate

or perhaps see the answer of this question ...

[How to mock private method for testing using PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7803944/1811730)