# Mocking a private method in junit using Powermockito

Tags: java, powermockito

I need to mock following method call `carBookBuilder.setTrip(protoConverter.convertTrip(carBookRequest, location))`, But When `carBookBuilder.setTrip(protoConverter.convertTrip(carBookRequest, location))` is calling i should just return mocking tripdetails and skip `protoConverter.convertTrip(carBookRequest, location)` method call.

**ProtoRequestAdapterTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProtoRequestAdapter})
class ProtoRequestAdapterTest {

    @Test
    public void testPopulateCarBookTest() {
        CarApiToProtoConverter carApiToProtoConverter;
        carApiToProtoConverter =  PowerMockito.mock(CarApiToProtoConverter.class);
        PowerMockito.when(carApiToProtoConverter.convertTripDetails(carBookRequest, locale)).thenReturn(tripDetails);
    }
}
```

**ProtoRequestAdapter.java**

```
class ProtoRequestAdapter {
     private CarBookRequest populateCarBook(BookingRequest bookingRequest) {
        CarBookRequest newCarBookReq = bookingRequest.getCarBookRequest();
        CarBookRequest.Builder carBookBuilder = CarBookRequest.newBuilder();

        ProtoConverter protoConverter =
                new ProtoConverter(refData, location);
        carBookBuilder.setTrip(protoConverter.convertTrip(carBookRequest, location));
        return carBookBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mock private method for testing using PowerMock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock)

Comment: I tried this one , but it won't work properly PowerMockito.when(spy, method(ProtoConverter.class, "convertTripDetails", CarBookRequest.class, Location.class))
                    .withArguments(anyObject(), anyObject())
                    .thenReturn(tripDetails);

Comment: On trying this am getting error as argument type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems here.
If I understand you correctly, you are trying to test 
`ProtoRequestAdapter#populateCarBook`.

First of all you should make the method public or at least protected, as otherwise your unit test can not call it.

Next the method you are trying to mock is `ProtoConverter#convertTrip`, which is not private, as otherwise your code would not compile.
More problematic is that you are instantiating it directly in your code, which makes it impossible to replace it with a mock.

I would strongly suggest you to inject it into your class (or at least move the instantiation into a (protected) `getProtoConverter()`-method, which you can overwrite in your test).

Comment: I would like to mock ProtoConverter#convertTrip which is a public method

Comment: If it is a public method, you do not need powermockito at all. Just use Mockito.mock(ProtoConverter.class) and user Mockito.when(protoConverterMock.convertTrip(Mockito.any(CarBookRequest.class, Mockito.any(Location.class)).thenReturn(yourObject) or something like that. The main difficulty here is get your mocked object into your class under test. That is why I suggested to make it settable from outside.
Theoretical you CAN intercept the constructor call with powermockito (although I never used this myself), but I wouldnt recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate `tripDetails` in your test class.

```
TripDetails tripDetails = new TripDetails();
tripDetails.setLocation = "London";
```