# Unit Testing Scheduler job in java

Tags: java, junit, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

We have a cron based job in our application.

The job class is as follows:

```
       public class DailyUpdate implements Job {

        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
                SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

testMethod();

}
        private void testMethod()
        {
System.out.pritnln("Executed From scheduler");
        }
        }
```

How should we write unit test case to test Method 
**testMethod()**

I cannot call testMethod Directly without scheduler as it is private..Any suggestion how to write unit test cases for Scheduler

Comment: there are other questions around the same problem. the answer is that you should never need to test a private method. If you want to do it, you can use reflection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes

Comment: @MarcoAltieri..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write a test you need to have an expected behavior so there is no point on testing a method that does nothing.

Now to your main problem. If you have somewhat of a legacy application, and you're not allowed to change the visibility of your methods, the best way to test private methods is to use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

So you can use the following pattern

```
Method testMethod = DailyUpdate.getDeclaredMethod(testMethod, argClasses);
testMethod .setAccessible(true);
return testMethod.invoke(targetObject, argObjects);
```

see also this question [how to test a class that has private methods fields or inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity, I would suggest you to use PowerMock (instead of coding it by yourself).
Here is a link explaining how to use it : [How to mock private method for testing using PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock)