# How to stub private methods of class under test by Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Say we have java class called SomeClass

```
public class SomeClass {

    private boolean isMethod() {

        return false;
    }

    public void sendRequest(String json, String text) {

        int messageId;

        if (isMethod()) {
            messageId = getMessageId(json);
            sendMessage(messageId, text);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(int messageId, String text) {

    }

    private int getMessageId(String text) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("messageId=(\\d+)&");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        if (m.find()) {
            return Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Don't pay attention to methods' name, they're all optional.

- I want to test `sendRequest(String json, String text)` method in isolation.
- I want to stub methods `isMethod()` and `getMessageId(json)`, and verify that `sendMessage(messageId, text)` method is called.
- I need to be sure that `getMessageId(json)` returns 25 and that `isMethod()` returns true no matter which argument value given.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This could be achieved by PowerMockito framework.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    private SomeClass someInstance;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        someInstance = PowerMockito.spy(new SomeClass());
    }

    @Test
    public void sendRequest() throws Exception {

        String json = "JSON";
        String text = "Some text";
        int messageId = 1;

        PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(someInstance, "isMethod");
        PowerMockito.doReturn(messageId).when(someInstance, "getMessageId", json);

        someInstance.sendRequest(json, text);

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(someInstance).invoke("isMethod");
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(someInstance).invoke("getMessageId", json);
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(someInstance).invoke("sendMessage", messageId, text);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please tell the documentation link for PowerMockito (not for poweMock)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what was said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189749/403431), I would add that the desire to test whether private method was called indicates that you are testing `implementation` as oppose to the `public contract of a class`. It is not an optimal idea, because it makes your refactoring more difficult. The idea of refactoring is that you can change inner workings of your code without violating it's contract. And your unit tests help you make sure that while changing the `implementation`, you did not introduce any changes to the `contract`.

So, in your case a better option would be to restructure your code so that your test calls public methods and verifies the result based on return values

Comment: even if I restructure my code by changing private methods to public. How can I can then stub those methods while testing `sendRequest(String json, String text)` method. When I mock `SomeClass` there would be no use, because `sendRequest(String json, String text)` would be stubbed. When I use spy method of Mockito, `sendRequest(String json, String text)` won't be stubbed, but other Mockito will call real methods of others methods (isMethod etc).

Comment: It's not about merely changing the signature of the method from `public` to `private`. Think what is the **responsibility** of the class you want to test? Imagine you have the following requirement, *Class A will send an HTTP request to endpoint X when value of some field stored in JSON property is higher than 50*. In this case the actual logic that you want to have covered with unit tests is the one that decided whether to send the request or not. And in case you want to test Class A, you would mock this logic (e.g. return `yes` to a question Should I send a request in one case)