# Facing Issue with Power Mockito Private Void Method Test Case

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito

I am using powermock.
I am facing issues with below scenario.

**UPDATE:**

My Question is different.
The example given in another link, has private method returning some value.
Here in my case both the methods are returning Void.

```
class ClassForWhichTestCasesIsPrepared {

    private void myPrivateMethod(String param1, MyBean param2) {
        //Some Code Here to save data
    }

    public void myPublicMethod() {
        //Some Code Here to find the require paramters to pass to below method

        myPrivateMethod(String param1, MyBean param2);
    }

}
```

Facing Issues for Writing Test Cases for `myPublicMethod` to Mock the private method in same class.

I want to mock the `myPrivateMethod` method, as it should not be called but `myPublicMethod` should be covered for test cases.
Both the methods are void.

I cannot change this design, I just have to complete and cover the required test cases for same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock private method for testing using PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock)

Answer (score 0):

You can use spy method provided by `PowerMock`.

e.g.

```
ClassForWhichTestCasesIsPrepared spy = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassForWhichTestCasesIsPrepared());

  when(spy, method(ClassForWhichTestCasesIsPrepared .class, "myPrivateMethod", 
  String.class, MyBean.class)).withArguments(anyString(), anyObject())
  .thenReturn(true);// this return can be made to do nothing as well if you want

spy.myPublicMethod();
```