# Junit test - how to mock class private member of type of private interface?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I wrote few junits, using some mocking techniques.
But stucked here:

```
public class Lookup {
    private LookupMethod lookupMethod;

    private interface LookupMethod {
        String lookup(String input);
    }

   public String treatString(@Nullable String input) {
       ...
       String lookupResult = lookupMethod.lookup(lookupInput);
       ...
   }
}
```

I'm unit testing the **treatString()** method and looking how to mock the **lookupMethod.lookup()** call in the **treatString()** method above.
I can't change **Lookup** class.

I'll appreciate a tip (example would be even better).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this class is **super hard** to test when you can't modify it.

Using the dark magic of `PowerMock` it should be possible to mock things by **name**, meaning that you provide a raw string denoting the method you want to override. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock) how to do that.

But as said: that is basically **dark** magic. It means to add PowerMock to your dependencies. Which will invite others to use PowerMock in the future. Which carries the risk of people writing **even more** hard to test code. Because you know have a tool that allows you to test that stuff. Instead of writing easy to test code.

And of course: in case someone else changes that class, like renaming that method, then your test breaks.

And then, ask yourself: what is the point of **testing** a class you aren't supposed to change? What if you find a bug, will it stay in?!